# cannot link simple dll solution

Tags: c++, dll

I try to make simple dll project in Visual Studio 2013 like in http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2009/12/10/how-to-create-a-dll-dynamic-link-library-in-c-as-visual-studio-2008-project/

But when i try to build solution it falls with an error:

```
error LNK1104: can not open file "D:\prj\dlltest1\Debug\dlltest1.lib"   D:\prj\dlltest1\ConsoleApplication1\LINK    ConsoleApplication1
```

But dlltest1 is dll-project. Why there is an .lib file?

Comment: Actually, VS generates .lib and .dll files. The .dll is the runtime library, which is needed at runtime execution of your .exe application. The .lib file is needed when you want to generate your .exe application

Comment: but why VS did not generate appropriate lib?

Comment: it is generated, check it better and adjust your Linker paths accordingly in your project settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated: The reason why no libs are generated because you have no symbols exported. I just checked your code.
You should have a *.h file define exported symbols like this.

```
#ifdef WIN32PROJECT1_EXPORTS
#define WIN32PROJECT1_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define WIN32PROJECT1_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif WIN32PROJECT1_API int fnWin32Project1(void);
```

1. When you created a DLL project, it has some exported symbols other project can use. These symbols' name and offset are stored in *.lib file. *.lib file is created with *.dll files, both of them are put in the output directory.
2. In the link stage of you ConsoleApplication, the linker try to find the symbols from all your referenced libs (defined in project property) and store these symbols' offset and source dll in output exe file.
3. You can change the libs settings in Property->Linker

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library#C_and_C.2B.2B) says:

> DLL compilation will produce both DLL and LIB files. The LIB file is used to link against a DLL at compile-time; it is not necessary for run-time linking.

The code within your application determines whether compile-time or run-time linking is required:

If you access your DLL functions like

```
__declspec(dllimport) someFunction(int firstArg, int secondArg)
```

then your compiler will require both the .dll and the .lib file for linking to the shared library, but during execution, only the .dll will be required.

If you however make use of the DLL functions `LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddress` and `FreeLibrary`, the .lib will not be required for linking.